# Software for SQL visualization of tables relations

Tags: mysql, sql, relationship

I have SQL file from my MYSQL database. How could I quick get the picture of tables relations, something like this:

[image: picture here]

It would be great if I could just import file to the software and it would output the view of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to load the file into a database with mysql utility :

```
mysql -u root -p db_name < file.sql
```

then you can open the database with a visual tool like [mysql workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) ...

Comment: Thank you. I tried to connect to workbench, I am not sure what is wrong, but I am not able to make a connection. IS there any software for offline creating visual files

Comment: failed to connect and denied access for the user. I use the same connection details as for the filezilla connecting to FTP

Comment: You should use credentials of your mysql database, not that one you use for the FTP connection ... Are two completely different things ...

Comment: it was problem with internet provider :) i didnt have full access.. thank you for the help!